# Recover .docx file from 'SAXParseException: "No namespace defined for pic"'

Tags: docx, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I cannot open a `.docx` file that I stored in a USB pendrive. I get following error and LibreOffice doesn't open the document:

```
File format error found at 
SAXParseException: "No namespace defined for pic"
SAXParseException: '[word/document.xml line 2]: Namespace prefix pic on txbx is not defined
', Stream 'word/document.xml', Line 2, Column 30767(row,col).
```

Is there any way to recover the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompress the `.docx` file. If you don't know how to do it, check it here:

https://superuser.com/a/1356829/707698

In the decompressed directory, look for the file `word/document.xml` and open it with a text editor. In the second line you'll see something like:

```
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
```

You have to include following attribute in that statement:

```
xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
```

After that you'll have something like this:

```
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" 
mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
```

Now you just need to rebuild the `.docx` file from the decompressed directory. If you don't know how to do it, check it here:

https://superuser.com/a/1356829/707698